# Upload Failed on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, office-365, file-upload

How do I solve this error when trying to upload a file or saving it to a location.

[image]

Comment: location means sharepoint or physical path

Comment: Does it happen only with specific file or others as well. It seems you don't have contribute permissions on the site you can just read items but not modify/upload.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure that**

- You have `EDIT` permission in the SharePoint Doc Library to can upload files.  or at least you have the below custom level permissions

  - Open Items,
  - Add Items,
  - View Items and
  - View Application Pages

  > **Note:** `READ` or `Vistors` is not sufficient to upload a file.
- If you made sure that your current user has the sufficient permission, so make sure that The login account is not your personal Microsoft account like outlook or live account.